# The signature of a product of surfaces

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology

If $\Sigma_1$ and $\Sigma_2$ are surfaces (i.e. compact, oriented 2-manifolds without boundary), is the signature $\tau (\Sigma_1 \times \Sigma_2)$ well-known? Recall that the signature is the difference $b_{2}^{+}-b_{2}^{-}$, where $b_{2}^{+}$  and $b_{2}^{-}$ are the number of $+1's$ and $-1's$, respectively, which are associated to the diagonalized quadratic form $Q_X(a,b)=\langle a \cup b, [M]\rangle$ defined on $H^2(M^4)\times H^2(M^4).$

I have a way of computing this signature for such a $4$-manifold and found that it is always $0$. I was not able to confirm this with any independent online source or publication, and I am hoping someone will be able to confirm or challenge this result.

Comment: You mean oriented, not orientable. The signature depends on a choice of orientation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The signature is $0$. One way to see this is that $\Sigma_1$ is a boundary, so $\Sigma_1 \times \Sigma_2$ is also a boundary, and the signature vanishes on boundaries. You can also directly compute the intersection form using the Kunneth formula.

Comment: More generally, the signature, when defined to be $0$ on compact oriented manifolds of dimension not divisible by $4$, is a genus, so it satisfies $\sigma(M \times N) = \sigma(M) \sigma(N)$ for compact oriented manifolds $M, N$ of any dimension. In particular, if either $M$ or $N$ has dimension not divisible by $4$, then $\sigma(M \times N) = 0$. I think this is also more or less a computation using the Kunneth formula.

Comment: Can you clarify how to compute the intersection form with the Künneth formula? I was under the impression that the Künneth formula gave the underlying group structure of the cohomology of a product, and said nothing of the ring structure, but I would savor being disabused of this conception.

Comment: I finally think I understand your first comment: Oriented surfaces are null cobordant (not sure of a reference for this), so if $\Sigma_1=\partial X$ then $\Sigma_1 \times \Sigma_2=\partial (X \times \Sigma_2)$. We have that the signature of a 4-manifold vanishes if it is the boundary of a 5-manifold, thus the result.

Comment: @Brian: the Kunneth formula tells you lots about the ring structure. The easiest statement is over a field, which suffices for the computation of the signature, where we have $H^{\bullet}(X \times Y, k) \cong H^{\bullet}(X, k) \otimes_k H^{\bullet}(Y, k)$ as graded rings. Here $\otimes_k$ refers to the graded tensor product, where multiplication is given by $(a \otimes b)(c \otimes d) = (-1)^{|b| |c|} ac \otimes bd$ on homogeneous elements.

Comment: @Brian: here's another argument. The signature reverses sign when you equip a manifold with the reverse orientation. But orientable surfaces admit orientation-reversing diffeomorphisms.

Comment: Is that Künneth formula statement somewhere in Hatcher? I'm a bit despondent that I seem to be forgetting my algebraic topology already.

Comment: @Brian: yes, it's Theorem 3.16. I left out finiteness hypotheses though.

Comment: I think it is equal to the product of signature of these two manifolds, i.e. $\tau(\Sigma_1\times\Sigma_2)=\tau(\Sigma_1)\times\tau(\Sigma_2)$.